# Whats the probability for a change in the context to conditioning an experiment?

Tags: probability

Let's say that there is an event which is only happening with a (assumed) probability of $0.05$ and has been seen to not happen $100$ times in a row. On the $101$ time there is a modification in the experiment and the event happens. I'd like to know (if it's possible) how to calculate the probability of the modification on the experiment been the cause of the occurrence of the event on the $101$th try.

Comment: You won't get a quantitative answer without two things:  A model of what the experiment change is, and a definition of what you mean by the "cause of the occurence."

Answer (score 0):

What you have described is a pretty bad experiment. The test for significance will be woefully underpowered, since your control group is size 100 and your treatment group is a sample of size 1: hence, even with a positive result for the first trial after changing the conditions, you will *not* be able to reject at the $\alpha=0.05$ level. You should opt for a balanced design: 50 for control, 50 for treatment. A sample size of 1 is useless unless the event is very rare (e.g., <1%).